# What is the best way of sizing a header logo in css

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a great way of sizing my logo to fit within the header, I am trying to get a result with the logo on the left side of the header and the naviagtion on the right side. I've tried this and it seems to work but I don't know if there's a better way to approach this. If anyone could give some tips it would be greatly appreciated.

My CSS and HTML

```css
a {
text-align: center;
color: #232323;
text-decoration: none;
transition: .1s;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  max-height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-wrapper img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
}

.get-started {
  background-color: #f27649;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border-radius: 3em;
}

.get-started:hover {
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="images/devchat.png" alt="DevTalk Logo">
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><button class="get-started" href="#">Get Started <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? What makes this worse than your anticipated method?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a more code efficient way to approach this @WaisKamal

Comment: I suspect it may not be code efficiency that you need, but something that gives good looking header on any size device. The max-width : 150px on the logo wrapper is rather specific and constraining, is there a reason for that? If not you could look at having the logo fit within a % of the header width perhaps, and/or give it max-height 100% and look into object-fit, just to get it to scale with the device.

Comment: I think this question should ask how to size an image instead of how to size a logo but I will definitely give your solution a try. Thanks! @AHaworth